# SFDX Permission set assign command failing in latest version 7.84

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, permission-sets

In earlier versions < 7.84.2
`sfdx force:user:permset:assign` command was working fine, but in latest version it is throwing error `Permission set "U" not found in target org. Do you need to push source?`

Does anybody faced the similar issue with latest version? and know what would be the possible root cause for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

When you compare the last release [v50](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_user.htm) with the older, It looks like you have to add double quote around usernames now

V48[image]

V50 [image]

UPDATE : a case has been logged https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/802 and the team ask to use `sfdx plugins:install user` until they release a patch

Comment: Thanks @Badbaxx. But it doesn't resolve the issue. At a matter of fact we already have the quotes around username.

Comment: I don't know if it is from your team but a case have been created on the subject https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/802

Comment: Thanks again @Badbaxx. That is exactly the issue. And I can confirm it resolves post applying the suggested workaround there.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use another workaround without having to install any plugin.

Just create a file `scripts/apex/assignCurrentUser.apex` with a code

```
PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'PermName'];
List<PermissionSetAssignment> psas = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();

for (Id uid: new List<Id>{UserInfo.getUserId()}) {
    psas.add(new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = uid, PermissionSetId = ps.Id));
}
insert psas;
```

and the bash file `assignCurrentUser.sh`

```
code=$(cat scripts/apex/assignCurrentUser.apex)        
echo "${code/PermName/$1}" > temp.apex
sfdx force:apex:execute -f temp.apex
rm temp.apex
```

and then just execute it

```
./assignCurrentUser.sh PermissionSetName
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that in the directory the permsets are missing, you might have to reload the source of the folder to populate the permsets directory under force-app/main/default